# SQL Copy data from row to row in same table with conditions

Tags: mysql

http://postimg.org/image/mchm444uv/

I want to copy like on picture data in one table in column 'morasaosiguranje' where sifra = sifra and fiskalnagodina from 23 to 24

So in my example all data must be same except value 0 in second row should be 1.

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with "all data" ? Which columns?

Comment: Please list the table columns in the post.

Comment: all data in second row remain unchanged except column 'morasaosiguranje'

Comment: so bassicly I need to copy data from one column in the table from row to row with condions (like on picture)

Comment: columns: kontniokvir,fiskalnagodina,sifra,opis,...,morasaosiguranje,...

Answer (score 0):

Your image is blocked for me at work but you'd have to do something like:

```
UPDATE table 
SET fiskalnagodina=a.fiskalnagodina, 
morasaosiguranje=a.morasaosiguranje  
FROM (SELECT TOP 1 morasaosiguranje, fiskalnagodina
        FROM table WHERE condition
        ORDER BY ID) a
WHERE condition
```

Comment: but I need to just copy the value, not adding by 1. can I send you the image on your e-mail